# Ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Открывается сайт с фильмами и парсится количество страниц, затем скрипт должен открывать каждый фильм с каждой страницы в новой вкладке и новая вкладка таки открывается, но без ссылки с фильмом, ошибка `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://rezka.ag"
driver.get(f"{url}/films")
page_count = int(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".b-navigation a")[-2].text)
for page_number in range(0, page_count+1):
    driver.get(f"{url}/films/page/{page_number}")
    for film in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".b-content__inline_item-cover a"):
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        get_film_link = str(film.get_attribute("href"))
        driver.get(get_film_link)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Вы сохраняете узел дерева в film, но после этого открываете новое окно и переключаетесь на него - с этого момента дерево html, которому принадлежит film, более не существует.

Comment: vitidev, я дописал ```driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])```, но дело в том, что новое окно открываетсяя без ссылки с фильмом, а просто пустое окно, после открытия которого моментально появляется ошибка

Comment: Еще раз. После открытия нового окна и переключения на него вы пытаетесь сделать `film.get_attribute("href")`, а дерево html, к которому принадлежит film, осталось на другой вкладке. Вычитайте все film в обычные питон словари и работайте. И даже новые вкладки не нужны - прямо в этой вкладке можно и открывать по очереди